# Check if array contains an object with the value of a specific property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of around 30 objects. Each object has a property called 'registration'. The registration property is what I use to uniquely identify each object. Each object also contains a timestamp (always unique).

Every 30 seconds I download a new instance of these 30 objects from an API. There is a possibility that a new object will be added to the current array. I need to come up with a way of checking if the new object is in the array of old (current) objects. If the objects didn't contain a unique timestamp then this would be very simple but as this varies for every instance this won't work.

What I have so far:

```
newDownloadedArray = JSON.parse(newDownloadedArray);

for (var i = 0; i < currentArrayObjects.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < newDownloadedArray.length; j++) {

         /* 
         *  This is where I'm stuck.
         *  I now need to check if newDownloadedArray[j].registration is
         *  the value of any registration property inside the currentArrayObjects
         *  array.
         *
         *  If it is, then I know this is a new object.
         */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
var isNewObject = function(newObject) {
    return !currentArrayObjects.some(function(currentObject) {
        return newObject.registration == currentObject.registration;
    });
};
var onlyNewObjects = newDownloadedArray.filter(isNewObject);
```

We're basically saying "For every object in `newDownloadedArray`, look at every object in `currentArrayObjects` until you find one that has a matching `registration`. If you do, that object is included in `onlyNewObjects`. If you don't, it isn't.

Note that [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) are only available in IE 9+, so you might want to use an equivalent helper method or utility library (like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)) if you want to support older browsers.

This isn't very efficient. For arrays of 30 items, we're doing work a worst-case of 900 times (if the new array was completely unique, because it has to search through all 30 of the `currentArrayObjects` for each one of the `newDownloadedArray`).

But that's not really a lot in browser terms. And you can do a lot to speed it up. For example, instead of searching through the `currentArrayObjects` in the predicate, we could build an object with all the registrations:

```
// We want a set of registrations, but JavaScript doesn't
// have a native set class, so we're going to use the keys 
// of an object to simulate sets, because object keys are
// basically sets of strings. Note that this won't work if
// registration isn't a string.
var currentRegistrations = {};
currentArrayObjects.forEach(function(currentObject) {
    // AKA currentRegistrationSet.add(currentObject.registration) if we
    // had an actual set class. I chose 'true' somewhat at random
    // because it felt right; we'll never actually be accessing
    // the value.
    currentRegistrations[currentObject.registration] = true;
});
var isNewObject = function(newObject) {
    // AKA !currentRegistrationSet.contains(newObject.registration) if we
    // had an actual set class.
    return !currentRegistrations.hasOwnProperty(newObject.registration);
}
var onlyNewObjects = newDownloadedArray.filter(isNewObject);
```

(Same caveat about [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))

Now we only have to do about 60 operations -- 30 to build the object ahead of time, and 30 more to check each one.

---

Your solution wasn't far off from the first one I posted. But you switched the `for` loops. It could be:

```
newDownloadedArray = JSON.parse(newDownloadedArray);

var onlyNewObjects = []
for (var i = 0; i < newDownloadedArray.length; i++) {
    var isNewObject = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < currentArrayObjects.length; j++) {
        if (newDownloadedArray[i].registration == currentArrayObjects[j].registration) {
            isNewObject = false;

            break; // no reason to keep looking; we know it isn't new
        }
    }
    if (isNewObject) {
        onlyNewObjects.push(newDownloadedArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For the record, I chose to go down the route of storing all registrations in their own array to keep things simple. It does mean having to manage another separate array but I think for speed and organisation purposes it's a great choice for this scenario.

Comment: @jskidd3 You should check out the comments I added to the second solution. Storing registrations in an array is not awful, but what you really want is to store the registrations in a set -- searching an an array is O(n); searching a hashset is constant time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using [lo-dash](http://lodash.com).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayotte/daJ5p/)

```
var newRegistrations = _.difference(
        _.pluck(newDownloadedArray, 'registration')
       , _.pluck(currentArrayObjects, 'registration')
);
```